# Database update on each button press

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Below is the code for a scoreboard app in which I am trying to maintain the teams score of a quiz show. The app works like that if you want to give marks to team A, first press A on key, then press button 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 for marks (+5, +10,+15,-5,-10 or -15).
I want to make a database for the marks and update them on each button press.

```
Label target = new Label();
int vA = 0;

private void frmScoreBoard_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) {
      target = lblScoreA;
   }

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B) {
      target = lblScoreB;
   }

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {
      target = lblScoreC;
   }

   if (target.Text != "") {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA += 5;

         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA += 10;
         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad3) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA += 15;
         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D4 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad4) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA -= 5;
         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D5 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad5) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA -= 10;
         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D6 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad6) {
         vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
         vA -= 15;
         target.Text = vA.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

I know the `ADO.NET` and connections but I don't know how to do the update each time. I don't need code - I just want the idea to how to do it.

code for ADO.NET :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblScore set Score='" + Convert.ToInt32(lblScoreA.Text) + "'where TeamName= '" + Convert.ToInt32(lblTeamA.Text) + "'", con);
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update tblScore set Score='" + Convert.ToInt32(lblScoreB.Text) + "'where TeamName= '" + Convert.ToInt32(lblTeamB.Text) + "'", con);
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update tblScore set Score='" + Convert.ToInt32(lblScoreC.Text) + "'where TeamName= '" + Convert.ToInt32(lblTeamC.Text) + "'", con);
   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: If i use parametrized queries then how to convert that to int???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate method for updating a team with score:

```
private void UpdateTeamScore(string teamName, int score) {

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
      con.Open();

      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblScore SET Score = @Score WHERE TeamName = @TeamName;", con)) {
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Score", score));
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TeamName", teamName));
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
}
```

And separate your KeyUp logic:

```
private String activeTeam = null;
private void frmScoreBoard_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

   // If the user used team selection keys
   if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.A) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.B) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)) {

      // Select the team according to pressed key
      ActivateTeamForScoring(e);

      // Return as we don't need to do anything else on this keystroke
      return;
   }

   // If the user came here by pressing the scoring keys
   else {

      // If a team wasn't set, return
      if (activeTeam == null) { return; }

      // Resolve the score according to pressed key
      int? score = ResolveScore(e);

      // If the user pressed correct score key, update
      if (score != null) {

         // Perform the score update to database
         UpdateTeamScore(activeTeam, score.Value);
      }

      // Reset active team after scoring
      activeTeam = null;
   }
}

private void ActivateTeamForScoring(KeyEventArgs e) {

   // Set the right team to be scored
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) {
      activeTeam = lblScoreA;
   } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B) {
      activeTeam = lblScoreB;
   } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {
      activeTeam = lblScoreC;
   }
}

private int? ResolveScore(KeyEventArgs e) {

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1) {
     return 5;
  } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2) {
     return 10;
  } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad3) {
     return 15;
  } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D4 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad4) {
     return -5;
  } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D5 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad5) {
     return -10;
  } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D6 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad6) {
     return -15;

  // If the keystroke was invalid, return null
  } else {
     return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The principle works... you'll need to open your connection before you start running command on it, so use

```
con.Open();
```

You could put all the UPDATEs together into a single command. Also the data in the text boxes is strings, so you don't need to convert it to an **int** first.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    con.Open();
    // Create one string with all the updates in it... 
    string query = string.Format("UPDATE tblScore SET Score={0} WHERE TeamName='{1}'; ", lblScoreA.Text, lblTeamA.Text);
    query += string.Format("UPDATE tblScore SET Score={0} WHERE TeamName='{1}'; ", lblScoreB.Text, lblTeamB.Text);
    query += string.Format("UPDATE tblScore SET Score={0} WHERE TeamName='{1}'; ", lblScoreC.Text, lblTeamC.Text);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```